# A way define order of subscribers in RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm looking a way to define order(?) of observers.

```
@GET("/get_user_msgs")
Observable<PrivateMessagesResponse> getPrivateMessages(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```

For example I gave a Observable from my Rest API created by Retrofit.

In my `ListView` I'm observing this `Observable`.

```
api.getPrivateMessages(params).subscribe(new Observer());
```

I also have an API wrapper for my Espresso tests and I'm subscribing to same `Observable` there. This way observer in API wrapper is called first and only then observer in `ListView` 
is called.

```
public class IdlingWrapper implements Api, IdlingResource { 
   ....

    public IdlingWrapper(Api realApi) {
        this.realApi = realApi;
    }

    ...

    public Observable<PrivateMessagesResponse> getPrivateMessages(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params); {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
        return wrapObservable(realApi.getPrivateMessages(params));
    }

    protected <T> Observable<T> wrapObservable(final Observable<PrivateMessagesResponse> observable) {
        //what to do here?
    }
}
```

Is there a way to force some observer to be notified after all others are done? Or something similar in that matter?

Something like

```
Observable observable = getObservable();
observable.subscribeAsLast(new LastObserver());
observable.subscribe(new ObserverA());
observable.subscribe(new ObserverB());
```

And so that `ObserverA` would be notified first, then `ObserverB` and only then `LastObserver`.

Or any other approach where I could find out when all registered observers were notified and completed.

Comment: I think you can create a new operator similar to "OperatorDoOnEach": https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/e676ddd8ec870fe53262a6168716c7a63b0a6167/rxjava-core/src/main/java/rx/operators/OperatorDoOnEach.java

Comment: How would that work? I don't have access to the `ObserverA` or `ObserverB`

Comment: So you want to call ObserverA, ObserverB, then LastObserver? Looks it's impossible. How an observable know there is no further observer?

Comment: Well, I really don't need `LastObserver` I just want to know when all registered observers (in this case `ObserverA` and `ObserverB`) were notified and completed or handled error. I'll update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do in IdlingWrapper, but I think the current implementation is very fragile.

I think the most important thing that needs to happen is to guarantee the observable can only be called once.

Here is a quick implementation to demonstrate that as well as my implementation of wrapObservable.

```
public class Test {

    private static int counter = 0;

    private static final List<Observable<?>> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    protected static <T> Observable<T> wrapObservable(final Observable<T> original) {
        // run atleast once???
        synchronized (list) {
            list.add(original);
        }

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Void> subscriber) {
                synchronized (list) {
                    counter++;
                    if (!list.contains(original)) {
                        subscriber.onError(new Exception("You can only subscribe once!"));
                        return;
                    }
                    list.remove(original);
                }

                // Sleep to make it easier to see things happening...
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }

                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }).flatMap(new Func1<Void, Observable<? extends T>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<? extends T> call(Void o) {
                return original;
            }
        }).finallyDo(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                synchronized (list) {
                    counter--;
                    if (list.size() == 0 && counter == 0) {
                        System.err.println("finally");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // running in io thread for simulating async call.
            Observable<String> test = wrapObservable(Observable.from("TEST!!!!!!")).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
            test.subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    System.err.println("completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    System.err.println("error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                    System.err.println("next");
                }
            });

            // example of calling the same observable twice.
            test.subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    System.err.println("completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    System.err.println("error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                    System.err.println("next");
                }
            });
        }

        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to make sure, that my observer in `IdlingWrapper` will be called last and not any other observer that subscribes to original observable.
And yes, my solution would break if there were 2 subscribers on original observable. This would work event better. Thanks! Not a fan on that sync list though...

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that this worked just fine.

```
protected <T> Observable<T> wrapObservable(final Observable<T> original) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribeFunc<T>() {
        @Override
        public Subscription onSubscribe(final Observer<? super T> t1) {
            original.subscribe(new Observer<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    t1.onCompleted();
                    uiThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            counter.decrementAndGet();
                            notifyIdle();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    t1.onError(e);
                    uiThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            counter.decrementAndGet();
                            notifyIdle();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(T args) {
                    t1.onNext(args);
                }
            });

            return Subscriptions.empty();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Look at finallyDo. The wrapper is doing exactly what that method is intended for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use built in RxJava methods to order your observers, you can use flatMap and range to turn each item into multiple items each with a priority and then filter on priority. Observers are ordered based on how they filter.

Here's a trivial example:

```
Observable<Pair<Integer, Object>> shared = RxView.clicks(findViewById(R.id.textView))
        .flatMap(c -> Observable.range(0, 2).map(i -> Pair.create(i, c)))
        .share();

shared.filter(p -> p.first == 1)
        .map(p -> p.second)
        .doOnSubscribe(c -> Log.d(TAG, "first subscribed doOnSubscribe"))
        .subscribe(c -> Log.d(TAG, "first subscribed onNext"));

shared.filter(p -> p.first == 0)
        .map(p -> p.second)
        .doOnSubscribe(c -> Log.d(TAG, "second subscribed doOnSubscribe"))
        .subscribe(c -> Log.d(TAG, "second subscribed onNext"));
```

If you are doing this all over the place